# I want to connect my twitteraccounthomepage info. But error"currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints"

Tags: twitter4j

`public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    try {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
        builder.setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
        builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();
        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();

        ResponseList<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
        System.out.println("Showing Home timeline :");
        for (Status status : statuses) {
            System.out.println(status.getUser().getScreenName() + " : " + status.getText());
        }
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}`

I can not fix the twitter web service connection problem.